# Update/Delete violate foreign key on either side

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, database-design

I have two tables, below are the strutures

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nl_address (
  id int NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  address_text varchar(100),
  pincode varchar(6),
  city_id int NOT NULL,
  state_id int NOT NULL,
  country_id int NOT null,
  is_active boolean default true,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY(city_id) REFERENCES nl_city(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_state_id FOREIGN KEY(state_id) REFERENCES nl_state(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_country_id FOREIGN KEY(country_id) REFERENCES nl_country(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nl_customer (
  cust_id int NOT NULL,
  prefix varchar(10) default 'CUST-',
  suffix varchar(2),
  org_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  domain_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  pan_number varchar(10) NOT null,
  pri_contact varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  pri_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  pri_email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  sec_contact varchar(10),
  sec_number varchar(10),
  sec_email varchar(30),
  is_active boolean default true,
  addr_id int not null,
  created_date date,
  created_by varchar(10),
  updated_date date,
  updated_by varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_address_id FOREIGN KEY(addr_id) REFERENCES nl_address(id)
);
```

The problem is, neither I am able to update or delete
If i am trying to update record in `nl_address`, I got an violation error that the field is used inside `nl_customer.

If i tried to update from `nl_customer`, then I got an violation error that the field is used inside `nl_address`

It was originated, when JPA trying to persist the data, I have inserted a dummy data with id 1, when JPA trying to insert another record then it throws

```
.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nl_address_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

It seems there is something wrong with the table structure, any help appreciated

Comment: please add your delete/update statements and error texts you receive. It is not very clear what you mean saying "If i tried to update from nl_customer, then I got an violation error" .

Comment: To avoid primary key violation, you can either use auto increment or  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) annotation for primary key in your Spring Entity

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is common that you cannot update or delete that belong to primary/foreign key if you generate duplicates, as all values should be unique (i.e. if you have already id=1 and update id=2 to id=1, you will get the error you mentioned) and because a foreign key construct is a specific relationship it should be clarified what will happen with this relationship.

1. In case of 'nl_address' you used 'GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY' which have the same purpose as SERIAL (i.e. auto increment), but it is more compliant with SQL standard. (I assume you are also aware of difference between GENERATED BY DEFAULT and GENERATED ALWAYS)
   However, you can specify the sequence in order to ensure the proper auto increment functionality.

```
ALTER TABLE nl_address 
ALTER COLUMN "id"
DROP IDENTITY IF EXISTS;

ALTER TABLE nl_address 
ALTER COLUMN "id"
ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT 1);
```

If you use UPDATE or DELETE on FOREIGN KEY construct ensure what should happen with relationship:

```
[CONSTRAINT fk_name]
   FOREIGN KEY(fk_columns) 
   REFERENCES parent_table(parent_key_columns)
   [ON DELETE delete_action]
   [ON UPDATE update_action]

/* as delete_action or update_action you can use e.g. SET NULL, RESTRICT or CASCADE;
so ensure what happen with records in related table*/
```